# XPath select node before current

Tags: c#, xpath

```
<table>
<tr>...</tr>
....
<tr>NodeToSelect</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr class="SomeClass">CurrentNode</tr>
...
</table>
```

I have an HtmlNode object which indicates `-tr class="SomeClass"CurrentNode-` in some function:

```
string Proccess(HtmlNode node)
{
    //need select 
}
```

How can i get node -NodeToSelect- from this function by Xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preceding-sibling::tr[text()="NodeToSelect"]
preceding-sibling::tr[2]
```

Comment: Let me know if you want an explanation of these. I can't tell if they're self-explanatory or not. I've done too much XPath. :)